# RDL Report not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, asp.net-core-mvc, rdl

I have this error when I generate the report.

Where can I set the connection of my rdl file?

AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.;An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.
Login failed for user ''.
---> AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing.

Here's my code.

````
         const int extension = 1;

         var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Reports", "test.rdl");
           
         var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "rp1", "Test Value to parameter" } };

         var localReport = new LocalReport(path);
            
         var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters);
            
         return File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf");```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkwzU.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below:-

```
 
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

public HomeController( IHostingEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
 {
           
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

 }





public async Task<IActionResult> Print()
 {

 string mimetype = "";

 int extension = 1;
 
 var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\test.rdlc";
 Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 parameters.Add("rp1", "Test Value to parameter");
           
 LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);

 var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimetype);
        
 return File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf"); 

}
```

Also, don't forget to install some NuGet packages as needed.

Hope it will resolve your issue. for more details and connected things, you can read this article:-

http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects

**UPDATE**

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="MyConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-N41V6ER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

**User ID** and **Password** means using SQL credentials, not Windows, but still very simple - just go into your Security section of your SQL Server and create a new Login. Give it a username and password, and give it rights to your database.

**AGAIN UPDATE(Data Source Connect)**

[image]

Now select the object and click next:-

[image]

below, the design of a simple report that allows displaying the (assume)product data in your connected database. then click finish.

[image]

then click the ok button:-

[image]

then you will find your database table in dataset:-

[image]

now you can drag and drop your data, which place you want to show in your report file.

[image]

.................................................................
.................................................................

**AGAIN UPDATE(Data base Connect)**

First right click on your report project- => Add=>New Item  then you will show:-

[image]

above add an entity data model to the windows form project.then click `Add`.then:-

[image]

[image]

Above,click `New Connection`.

[image]

Above,click `Continue`.

[image]

Above, give your server name. my machine has just one (SQL server)installed for that i am using `.` and select SQL  Server in Authentication box.

[image]

Above,then click `Ok`.you have obisouly select DB name which you want.

[image]

[image]

Above, type your DB name carefully which you already selected.

[image]

[image]

Above, I select my product table because I will show that. then click `finish`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response but where should I put the sql server credentials for my report? The rdl file has a data source.

Comment: @Clefor7 for put credentials in your connectiononstring, you have to update your code in web. config in your Form file.i updated my answer, please check.

Comment: I already has a login credentials and it is working but when I open the report this error well show "Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. Login failed for user ''. It looks like there is no connection in my rdl file. I try to save the credentials in the report but no luck.

Comment: My problem here is that how can I set the dataset connection of my rdl file inside c#.

Comment: @Clefor7 I again updated my answer. I described step by step, how to set your dataset connection in your rdlc file inside c#. please check it.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but instead of Object in data source I used the database option but got this error when I open the report.

AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.;An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.

Comment: @Clefor7 Did you connect your DB by using ```ADO.Net entity data model``` before doing my posted task?   and please follow my task step by step after doing connect your DB by using ```ADO.net data model```.if you did not know how to connect your rdlc file and DB. then please let me know. I will also post it.

Comment: @Clefor7 i updated my answer, first follow my ```AGAIN UPDATE(Data base Connect)``` then follow my ```AGAIN UPDATE(Data base Connect)``` post. hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: yes I added a connection to my db, my problem now is I don't have a app.config file because I'm using asp.net core web api.

Comment: Do you have a sample source code? asp.net core web api with rdlc report?

Thanks.

Comment: @Clefor7 first of all, if you have an asp.net Core web API. it's ok. I assume you create another windows application in the same solution explorer. definitely, here have an ```app. config``` file for the connection. I actually have a project this related, and I used rdlc report my project.  I actually don't understand why have not app.config file!! definitely should have. please tell me how you took windows application from for make rdlc in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much, now my rdlc is connected to my database. My other problem is how can I use this rdlc file in my .net core web api project.